# How to change the window size after the program starts?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I want that after starting the program, it checks its actual size and when "window.winfo_width > 520" it changes its size to 520. Is it possible?

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *

def upd():
    tstr = strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
    ltime.config(text=tstr)

    lday.config(text=strftime("%A"))

    dtstr = strftime("%B %d, %Y")
    ldate.config(text=dtstr)
    ltime.after(1000, upd)


window = Tk()
window.config(bg='black')
window.title("Clock")
window.geometry('520x300')
window.resizable(0,1)


ltime = Label(window, font="Adobe 60", text='', fg='green', bg='black')
ltime.pack()
lday = Label(window, font="Adobe 60", text='', fg='green', bg='black')
lday.pack()
ldate = Label(window, font="Adobe 60", text='', fg='green', bg='black')
ldate.pack()

upd()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `window.winfo_geometry()` will give you the geometry of the window.

For getting width only, use `window.winfo_width()`.

For getting height only, use `window.winfo_height()`

e.g.

```
if window.winfo_width() > 520 :
     window.geometry('520x300')
```

---

Now, since you are using `window.resizable(0,1)`, you are disabling the window's width to be resized, so windows's width will be fixed to 520.
So, how will it exceed 520, if it's not resizable?
If you enable it, and then want window's width to not exceed 520:

Tkinter offers `.maxsize()` and `.minsize()` to fix the size of the root window.

e.g. if you want that the window's width to not exceed 520, then just set the width in `maxsize` as 520.

```
window.geometry('520x300')
window.maxsize(520, 300)
```

The window's width will not be resized more than 520 now.

---

In case, you want to resize according to the user's screen's size:

To get the screen size, you can use `winfo_screenwidth()` which returns the screen `width` and `winfo_screenheight()` for the `height` of the screen in pixels.

`window.geometry()` can be recalled if needed.

---

EDIT: An example of recalling `window.geometry()` after the start of program(, even after resizing is disabled horizontally):

```
def resizeScreen():
    window.geometry('520x300')

b = Button(window, text="RESIZE", command=resizeScreen)
b.pack()
```

Whenever this button is clicked, the screen will be resized, from what it is currently.
You can call this same function without using a button, by just calling the function. It depends on your code, how you use it.

Comment: Read the question carefully.  OP wants to keep the width of the window *not greater than 520*.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for pointing it out. Is this fine now? Or have I misunderstood the question completely?

Comment: @Kartikeya yes, thank you, everything is as I wanted. about the fact that my window can not be more than 520: it can be more than 520 because I have limited the ability to resize the window only horizontally ***window.resizable(0,1)***.

but is it possible to adjust the window size after the start of the program?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned that `window.resizable(0,1)` will disable the resizing of your **`width`** (horizontal window size) but only for the user. You (the developer) can call `window.geometry()` any time to resize it. Edited my answer with an example to this.